# Как сделать отступ между вкладками?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Как сделать отступ между вкладками больше на python используя tkinter[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
     from tkinter import *
     from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
     import ctypes

     user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
     screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(78),          user32.GetSystemMetrics(79)


     window = Tk()
     note = Notebook(window)
     ms = Frame(note)
     note.add(ms, text = "Первая вкладка")
     mn = Frame(note)
     note.add(mn, text = "Вторая вкладка")
     note.pack(fill=BOTH)

     window.title("Программа")
     window.resizable(False, False)
     window.geometry(f"{screensize[0]}x{screensize[1]}")


     window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можетет создать свой стиль и привязать его.
TabMargin - внешний отступ.
Padding - внутренний отступ.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import  ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

test = ttk.Notebook(root)
test.pack()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create( "MyStyle", parent="alt", settings={
        "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [5, 5, 5, 5]}},
        "TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [25, 25, 25, 25]}, }})

style.theme_use("MyStyle")

frame1 = Frame(test, width=500, height=500, bg="red")
frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

frame2 = Frame(test, width=500, height=500, bg="blue")
frame2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

test.add(frame1, text="Frame1")
test.add(frame2, text="Frame2")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, нужно чтобы появился зазор между вкладками. tabmargins влияет на отступ вокруг вкладок (между вкладками все так же нет зазора), padding влияет на отступ границ вкладки до названия вкладки.

Comment: Нет, вы почти правильно поняли, но нужен как раз зазор между вкладками